# Why return Task<int> instead of int? (async & await)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Lets say I run `RunSynchron()`. In this case it runs `Delay()` which pause for 10 seconds and while that it continues with the program. After `Delay()` is done, it returns the value 1 for the `if`-statement. But why do I have to return a `Task<int>` instead of an `int`?

```
class Synchron
{
    public async void RunSynchron()
    {
        var delay = this.Delay();
        Console.WriteLine("Now we wait...");
        Console.WriteLine("But we can continue with our work");

        if(await delay == 1)
            Console.WriteLine("Now it's done");

    }

    public async Task<int> Delay()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the compiler's way of wrapping the result in the proper MT environment - setting aside the result so it know it will be coming in from another thread. It saves you a ton of time when working in MT environments, and the result is still an integer!

Comment: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `async` keyword is just a syntactic sugar around a method which returns a task. That is its definition.

Under the hood, when the compiler encounters `await` on the same method call, it will add complete asynchronous call and waiting for completion of the task. Therefore, compiler requires a `Task<int>` to construct the code for you, the code that ultimately compiles.

Note that the code that follows `await` is coded as task continuation on the task returned from the method. There is quite a lot of boilerplate if you tried to write it yourself. That is why `async/await` keywords are so useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's an unfortunate aspect of the design of the `async`/`await` feature that `async` appears to be a part of the *declaration* of the method.

I say unfortunate because it is an *implementation* detail about the method - specifically, it changes the nature of the code that may appear within such a method, such that `await`s are allowed to appear and will be appropriately dealt with.

It doesn't change the *signature* of a method (indeed, it's not allowed within interface declarations). As such, if you have a method that returns "something", and at a later point in time that "something" can be transformed into an `int`, you're not describing a method that returns `int`. In your example, you're storing that "something" in your `delay` variable. It's not an `int` at that point - just something that can be turned into an `int` later.

They could have chosen to make `async` "more magic" by having it implicitly change the method signature to wrap the result in a `Task` - but that would have made that actual return type less obvious to casual inspection. It would also require more actual editing if one wants to transform a method from being `async` to non-`async` or vice versa (you'd also have to edit the return types)